# What is the difference between $variables['elements']['#node'] and $variables['node']?

Tags: theming

Just wonder what is the difference between `$variables['elements']['#node']` and `$variables['node']` in `hook_preprocess_node()`. Are the same instance of the same node?

Comment: The part I removed was already asked in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251914/where-can-i-find-the-documentation-for-xxx-preprocess-node-hook which was closed. Asking where to find documentation is off-topic for us, together any question asking where to find off-site resources. We assume you know of api.drupal.org and the documentation on drupal.org.

Answer (score 2):

See the code executed in [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.5.x), the function called before the preprocess functions implemented by modules for a node.

```
$variables['node'] = $variables['elements']['#node'];
```

So, yes, `$variables['node']` and `$variables['elements']['#node']` contain the same value.

Comment: Why you removed my question on $variables variable. It seems this forum is over moderated.

Comment: The _Where do I find more documentation?_ part is off-topic for us, but you find the answer in the answer I posted. Also, this is not a forum, but a Q&A site.